# Flask Mail: how to add custom name to the sender?

Tags: flask, flask-mail

I'm using Flask mail to send emails. Everything works fine except I noticed the sender name is just a first part of email like (1) - "info" in this case:

[image]

How to add a custom name like (2) - see the screenshot?

The code I'm sending emails with:

```
def send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)


def send_email(to, subject, template, **kwargs):
    app = current_app._get_current_object()
    msg = Message(app.config['MAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX'] + ': ' + subject,
                sender=app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] , recipients=[to])
    msg.body = render_template(template + '.txt', **kwargs)
    msg.html = render_template(template + '.html', **kwargs)
    thr = Thread(target=send_async_email, args=[app, msg])
    thr.start()
    return thr
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set sender as tuple like so:

```
Message(
    sender=('Firstname Lastname', 'from@me.com')
)
```